# DataGridTemplateColumn Binding Using a TextBox in WPF with MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have a DataGrid that is bound to a List (ListOne). Inside the grid I'd like to display an extra TextBox that contains fields found in another Class that is not the same as the Class used in ListOne.

I've done this before with a ComboBox using the DataGridTemplateColumn, the problem is I'm not sure how the Binding would work when using a TextBox?

ListOne contains code and description which is bound and displays correctly. My SQL Stored Procedure returns extra values using a Join, which I'd like to display as editable fields ListOne.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably try to bind the DataGrid directly to the joined data as i imagine that doing joins directly in the cells may be difficult and round-about.